# Installing fabric8 in linux VM machine

Tags: linux, kvm, fabric8, minikube

I am installing fabric8 on my linux VM machine. I have followed the steps which is mentioned in the guide. I have installed KVM drive and downloaded fabric8 binary code. After that when I tried gofabric8 start command I am getting the following error. Any suggestions?

```
Unable to download driver Driver install for linux not yet supported
minikube is already available on your PATH
kubectl is already available on your PATH
funktion is already available on your PATH
```

**There are no extra logs I can see. So run the minikube. Details are given below.**

**Command I used**

```
/root/.fabric8/bin/minikube start --vm-driver=kvm --v=7
```

log message

```
Starting local Kubernetes cluster...
Found binary path at /usr/local/bin/docker-machine-driver-kvm
Launching plugin server for driver kvm
Plugin server listening at address 127.0.0.1:41218
() Calling .GetVersion
Using API Version  1
() Calling .SetConfigRaw
() Calling .GetMachineName
(minikube) Calling .GetState
(minikube) DBG | Getting current state...
(minikube) DBG | Fetching VM...
***(minikube) Failed to fetch machine
(minikube) DBG | panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer*** dereference
(minikube) DBG | [signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x4d7167]
(minikube) DBG |
(minikube) DBG | goroutine 22 [running]:
(minikube) DBG | panic(0x8c54a0, 0xc82000a100)
(minikube) DBG |        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:464 +0x3e6
(minikube) DBG | github.com/alexzorin/libvirt-go.(*VirDomain).GetState(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
(minikube) DBG |        /home/daniel/go/src/github.com/alexzorin/libvirt-go/domain.go:192 +0x87
(minikube) DBG | github.com/dhiltgen/docker-machine-kvm.(*Driver).GetState(0xc8201320e0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
(minikube) DBG |        /home/daniel/go/src/github.com/dhiltgen/docker-machine-kvm/kvm.go:450 +0x70
(minikube) DBG | github.com/docker/machine/libmachine/drivers/rpc.(*RPCServerDriver).GetState(0xc8200e3b60, 0xe0d430, 0xc820154910, 0x0, 0x0)
(minikube) DBG |        /home/daniel/go/src/github.com/docker/machine/libmachine/drivers/rpc/server_driver.go:191 +0x45
(minikube) DBG | reflect.Value.call(0x8858a0, 0x93fe88, 0x13, 0x959cd0, 0x4, 0xc82002def8, 0x3, 0x3, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
(minikube) DBG |        /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:435 +0x120d
(minikube) DBG | reflect.Value.Call(0x8858a0, 0x93fe88, 0x13, 0xc82002def8, 0x3, 0x3, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
(minikube) DBG |        /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:303 +0xb1
(minikube) DBG | net/rpc.(*service).call(0xc82004dac0, 0xc82004d880, 0xc820154080, 0xc8200a9680, 0xc8201506a0, 0x7e14a0, 0xe0d430, 0x16, 0x89fca0, 0xc820154910, ...)
(minikube) DBG |        /usr/local/go/src/net/rpc/server.go:383 +0x1c2
(minikube) DBG | created by net/rpc.(*Server).ServeCodec
(minikube) DBG |        /usr/local/go/src/net/rpc/server.go:477 +0x49d
E0119 09:42:23.506636    7110 start.go:96] Error starting host: Error getting state for host: unexpected EOF.

 Retrying.
E0119 09:42:23.507014    7110 start.go:102] Error starting host:  Error getting state for host: unexpected EOF
```

Comment: Can you provide the full error message?

Comment: Added the logs above

Comment: That's a real hard one... no idea ;(

Comment: latest error :  E0123 15:51:12.041055   19445 start.go:83] Error starting host: Error creating new host: Error attempting to get plugin server address for RPC: Failed to dial the plugin server in 10s. Retrying